# Alter column type of multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to change type of multiple columns in a one table to varchar(50) (in a single SQL query). Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong, and why this query shows error.

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table_name' 
    ALTER COLUMN 'col1' varchar(50), 
    ALTER COLUMN 'col2' varchar(50), 
    ALTER COLUMN 'col3' varchar(50)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Get rid of the single quotes?

Comment: What you want to change? Column name, type, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotation marks and use `MODIFY` not `CHANGE COLUMN`

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name 
    MODIFY col1 varchar(50), 
    MODIFY col2 varchar(50), 
    MODIFY col3 varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `MODIFY` and get rid of the single quotes:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table_name 
    MODIFY col1 varchar(50), 
    MODIFY col2 varchar(50), 
    MODIFY col3 varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you want is:

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table_name'  
modify COLUMN 'col1' varchar(50),   
modify COLUMN 'col2' varchar(50),   
modify COLUMN 'col3' varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CHANGE` you would need to specify the `new_col_name` then `col_definition` :

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table_name` 
CHANGE COLUMN `col1` `col1` varchar(50),   
CHANGE COLUMN `col2` `col2` varchar(50),   
CHANGE COLUMN `col3` `col3` varchar(50)
```

Using `MODIFY` you only need specify the `col_definition`:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table_name` 
MODIFY COLUMN `col1` varchar(50),   
MODIFY COLUMN `col2` varchar(50),   
MODIFY COLUMN `col3` varchar(50)
```

[mysql_manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change column definition only (without renaming), you can use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table_name' 
    MODIFY 'col1' varchar(50)
```

else you must use this syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE 'my_table_name' 
    CHANGE 'col1old', 'col1new' varchar(50)
```